# Puppeteer: TypeError: Readable is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer, serverless

I have been trying to use Puppeteer@15.5.0 to generate a PDF on the server side in Node.js.

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';

...

const browser = await launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent('COME ON!');
console.log(await page.content());
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf();
```

The `console.log` statement gives me the expected output of `<html><head></head><body>COME ON!</body></html>`

It then runs into the following error:

```
Error:
TypeError: Readable is not a constructor
    at getReadableFromProtocolStream (/Users/kaziehsanaziz/Work/DocSpace/repos/docspace-pay/.webpack/service/src/public-lambda.js:405775:12)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Page.pdf (/Users/kaziehsanaziz/Work/DocSpace/repos/docspace-pay/.webpack/service/src/public-lambda.js:403129:26)
    at async /Users/kaziehsanaziz/Work/DocSpace/repos/docspace-pay/.webpack/service/src/public-lambda.js:329729:31
```

Comment: I am working on something similar and have that same error when I use ncc to compiling everything to a single file. When I compile with tsc, I don't get this error. How are you compiling? Share the scripts bock of package.json

Comment: I've also run into it. The puppeteer issue is here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer cannot be bundled using Webpack. The issue was that I was trying to do just that. In my case, since I was using Serverless, the solution was to tell the [serverless-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-bundle) plugin to not bundle the Puppeteer.

```
bundle:
  packager: yarn
  esbuild: true
  forceExclude:
    - aws-sdk
    - puppeteer
  externals:
    - puppeteer-core
    - '@sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda'
```

The `forceExclude` is doing the trick here for the local environment. The `external` is what's helping the Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this issue. It occurs when webpack (v5 on my end) bundles puppeteer. I have solved it by explicitly declaring webpack ignore directive when importing a file which uses puppeteer. I did this via dynamic es import, but a static one could be done in a very similar way:

```js
const loadModule = async (modulePath) => {
  try {
    return await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ modulePath)
  } catch (e) {
    throw new ImportError(`Unable to import module ${modulePath}`)
  }
}

const renderPdf = (await loadModule('../../renderPdf/index.js')).default
```

Answer (score -2):

use `require puppeteer` instead of `import puppeteer` statement

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.